# Connecting to postgresql database

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I keep getting an authentication error when trying to connect to a postgresql database. Here is the specific error:

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.Message:FATAL: password authentication failed for user
```

I've checked and double checked the username and password, so this is not the issue. I was able to successfully connect using psql to this very same database. Here is what my application.conf looks like

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
#Database configuration using PostgreSQL database engine
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://website.com/database"
db.default.user="username"
db.default.password="password")

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/),
# by providing an application-logger.xml file in the conf directory.

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG

                                                    68,0-1        Bot
```

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: speculation: any special chars in the pwd being used?

Comment: it is strictly alpha-numeric

Comment: Sorry failed to read the question fully. Initial comment not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.default.password="password")
```

the ) is a typing error?
If not, remove it and try again.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to worry about your own intelligence, thank yo u very much this was the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/mydb"
```

This works fine for me, I don't event use the `db.default.user` and `db.default.password`